# Model based on huge Amazon review Dataset not converging quickly

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I was trying to replicate the results from the Hierarchical Attention Model paper where they train on the Amazon Reviews Dataset. I needed it for a multi-output classification for reviews and sentiment. Pretty basic, right? But the problem is that the dataset is too large(almost 4.2M reviews) and I end up with a batch size of over 6000 on a single colab GPU.

This is probably causing my loss to not converge as efficiently. I have added multiple BatchNorm layers and it really did help my over-fitting problem but I don't know if its too much and if its the major reason for it not converging as quickly. At this moment, the loss decreases constantly but messing around with the learning rate too much just causes the model to diverge eventually. This is the general trend:

```
lr<0.001 - Very slow convergence 
lr = 0.001 -Moderately slow, much better than before
lr = 0.01 - Best as of now 
lr = 0.1 - Decent 
lr > 0.1 - Diverges slowly
```

This is the continuation of training from the previously saved model

```
Train on 4233936 samples, validate on 235219 samples
Epoch 1/10
4233936/4233936 [==============================] - 666s 157us/sample - loss: 1.6747 - dense_3_loss: 1.0357 - dense_4_loss: 0.6390 - dense_3_accuracy: 0.5517 - dense_3_precision: 0.6631 - dense_3_recall: 0.3783 - dense_4_accuracy: 0.7368 - dense_4_precision: 0.7655 - dense_4_recall: 0.6994 - val_loss: 1.6442 - val_dense_3_loss: 1.0197 - val_dense_4_loss: 0.6241 - val_dense_3_accuracy: 0.5669 - val_dense_3_precision: 0.6647 - val_dense_3_recall: 0.4266 - val_dense_4_accuracy: 0.7404 - val_dense_4_precision: 0.7636 - val_dense_4_recall: 0.7129
Epoch 2/10
4233936/4233936 [==============================] - 666s 157us/sample - loss: 1.5674 - dense_3_loss: 0.9750 - dense_4_loss: 0.5924 - dense_3_accuracy: 0.5782 - dense_3_precision: 0.6701 - dense_3_recall: 0.4297 - dense_4_accuracy: 0.7601 - dense_4_precision: 0.7816 - dense_4_recall: 0.7329 - val_loss: 1.5835 - val_dense_3_loss: 0.9839 - val_dense_4_loss: 0.5992 - val_dense_3_accuracy: 0.5734 - val_dense_3_precision: 0.6469 - val_dense_3_recall: 0.4583 - val_dense_4_accuracy: 0.7509 - val_dense_4_precision: 0.7693 - val_dense_4_recall: 0.7287
Epoch 3/10
4233936/4233936 [==============================] - 669s 158us/sample - loss: 1.5379 - dense_3_loss: 0.9581 - dense_4_loss: 0.5798 - dense_3_accuracy: 0.5855 - dense_3_precision: 0.6728 - dense_3_recall: 0.4437 - dense_4_accuracy: 0.7663 - dense_4_precision: 0.7858 - dense_4_recall: 0.7415 - val_loss: 1.5628 - val_dense_3_loss: 0.9722 - val_dense_4_loss: 0.5901 - val_dense_3_accuracy: 0.5883 - val_dense_3_precision: 0.6713 - val_dense_3_recall: 0.4607 - val_dense_4_accuracy: 0.7657 - val_dense_4_precision: 0.7840 - val_dense_4_recall: 0.7426
Epoch 4/10
4233936/4233936 [==============================] - 668s 158us/sample - loss: 1.5190 - dense_3_loss: 0.9477 - dense_4_loss: 0.5714 - dense_3_accuracy: 0.5896 - dense_3_precision: 0.6743 - dense_3_recall: 0.4525 - dense_4_accuracy: 0.7700 - dense_4_precision: 0.7883 - dense_4_recall: 0.7469 - val_loss: 1.5349 - val_dense_3_loss: 0.9565 - val_dense_4_loss: 0.5783 - val_dense_3_accuracy: 0.5868 - val_dense_3_precision: 0.6616 - val_dense_3_recall: 0.4625 - val_dense_4_accuracy: 0.7678 - val_dense_4_precision: 0.7882 - val_dense_4_recall: 0.7422
Epoch 5/10
4233936/4233936 [==============================] - 666s 157us/sample - loss: 1.5044 - dense_3_loss: 0.9395 - dense_4_loss: 0.5649 - dense_3_accuracy: 0.5931 - dense_3_precision: 0.6753 - dense_3_recall: 0.4594 - dense_4_accuracy: 0.7730 - dense_4_precision: 0.7904 - dense_4_recall: 0.7511 - val_loss: 1.5274 - val_dense_3_loss: 0.9492 - val_dense_4_loss: 0.5780 - val_dense_3_accuracy: 0.5918 - val_dense_3_precision: 0.6750 - val_dense_3_recall: 0.4578 - val_dense_4_accuracy: 0.7740 - val_dense_4_precision: 0.7927 - val_dense_4_recall: 0.7507
Epoch 6/10
4233936/4233936 [==============================] - 667s 158us/sample - loss: 1.4916 - dense_3_loss: 0.9324 - dense_4_loss: 0.5592 - dense_3_accuracy: 0.5962 - dense_3_precision: 0.6763 - dense_3_recall: 0.4652 - dense_4_accuracy: 0.7757 - dense_4_precision: 0.7922 - dense_4_recall: 0.7548 - val_loss: 1.5183 - val_dense_3_loss: 0.9466 - val_dense_4_loss: 0.5714 - val_dense_3_accuracy: 0.5927 - val_dense_3_precision: 0.6665 - val_dense_3_recall: 0.4788 - val_dense_4_accuracy: 0.7679 - val_dense_4_precision: 0.7822 - val_dense_4_recall: 0.7505
```

Loss and Optimizer. I tried categorical crossentropy and hinge but it gave similar results. So I thought I'd give Kullback Divergence a shot(I have never tried this optimizer but looks like its working well)

```
Loss - kullback_leibler_divergence 
optimizer=SGD(learning_rate=0.01,momentum=0.6,clipvalue=0.3)
```

```
    input_layer = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=shape)

    embedding = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(VOCAB+1,128,input_length=100,mask_zero=True)(input_layer)
    gru = tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(32,return_sequences=True,recurrent_dropout=0.2))(embedding)

    bn = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(gru)


    gru1 = tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(50,recurrent_dropout=0.2,return_sequences=True))(bn)

    bn1 = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(gru1)

    attention = tf.keras.layers.TimeDistributed(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1,activation='tanh',use_bias=False))(bn1)
    attentionf = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(attention)
    attentiona = tf.keras.layers.Activation('softmax')(attentionf)

    merge = tf.keras.layers.dot([gru1,attentiona],axes=1) 

    bn2 = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(merge)

    dense = tf.keras.layers.Dense(256,activation='selu')(bn2)
    drop = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.3)(dense)
    dense1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(128,activation='selu')(drop)
    bn3 = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(dense1)
    dense_rating_1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(5,activation='softmax')(bn3)
    dense_sentiment_1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(3,activation='softmax')(bn3)

    model = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=input_layer,outputs=[dense_rating_1,dense_sentiment_1])
```

Comment: try training on a smaller subset of the data. Increase dense layer to 0.5 if over fitting is still an issue. Change all your activation function except the last into `relu`

Comment: @Kenan I actually had it on relu but hinge loss didn't take it well so I changed it to selu to avoid nans. About the dataset, I am actually already training on a subset (entire dataset is ~10M). I need this entire dataset if it's possible despite the problem being a very basic one. I am keeping it as a last alternative to reduce it's dataset size. Also, increasing the dropout sizes has led to underfitting in the past but if you insist I'll try it out. Any other things I should keep in mind?

Comment: i would keep sleu then for all layers except the last one. Add batchnorm between `dense` and `drop`, try dropout of 0.35

Comment: @Kenan I tried doing this but it still doesn't converge very well. It becomes very slow aa the epochs increase. Is the zero padding adding too much noise? I have a maxlen of padding set to 100 words. I'll try to lower this and see but apart from that  it's almost exactly the same

Comment: Reduce the amount of Dense in your previous layers. Too much padding will make the signal very weak among the noise. Also increase the number of epochs, maybe your model is converging but needs more time